# nested loops TXMLMap Talend

Tags: talend

I have a problem when I'm trying to read XML from tRestclient > tXMLMap

[image]

tRestclient GET message :

```
<content type="application/xml">
<mSmiley Tongueroperties>
<d:FileSystemObjectType >0</d:FileSystemObjectType>
<d:Id>13</d:Id>
<d:Title>health</d:Title>
<d:c3vxId m:type="Collection(Edm.Int32)">
<d:element>198</d:element>
<d:element>101</d:element>
</d:c3vxId>

</properties>

<properties>
<d:FileSystemObjectType >1</d:FileSystemObjectType>
<d:Id>13</d:Id>
<d:Title>human</d:Title>
<d:c3vxId m:type="Collection(Edm.Int32)">
<d:element>200</d:element>
<d:element>101</d:element>
</d:c3vxId>
</properties>

<properties>
<d:FileSystemObjectType >2</d:FileSystemObjectType>
<d:Id>13</d:Id>
<d:Title>technology</d:Title>
<d:c3vxId m:type="Collection(Edm.Int32)">
<d:element>108</d:element>
<d:element>101</d:element>
</d:c3vxId>

</pperties>
</content
```

the problem is that I can't loop on   because it's a child node.

[image]
[image]
Do you have any solutions for this please ?

thank's

Data Integration

Comment: What is your expected output please ?

Comment: thank's @iMezouar but I'm actually using tExtractXMLField and it's working fine for me ¨!